# Running multiple test classes in same file with ReSharper v9.2?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper, resharper-9.0

I used to be able to hit Ctrl+U,R to run all test classes inside a given file using ReSharper (NUnit is mytest harness).
For example, here is my class layout:

```
public static class TestsForT
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class WhenTDoesThis
    {
        [Test]
        public void ThisHappens()
        {
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class WhenTDoesThat
    {
        [Test]
        public void ThatHappens()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

All I would have to do was to place my cursor at the top of the file (over the static class declaration), then hit Ctrl+U,R and ReSharper would look at ALL the TestFixtures in my file and run all of them for me.

Now, unless my cursor is directly on the same line as the [TestFixture] attribute, ReSharper cannot run all unit tests in the file. If can only run one test at a time.

What magic ReSharper setting am I missing here? I don't want to run each unit test one at a time, b/c we can have up to 30 classes with the [TextFixture] attribute in one static test class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to do it in one click? Otherwise you can locate current document in solution explorer `Shift+Alt+L` and then run all tests.

Comment: Kote, I know the Shift+Alt+L shortcut. Sounds like once I find the file in solution explorer, that I click on it then Ctrl+U,R?

Comment: Once you locate the file, it will be already selected. So you don't need to click on it. Just press two shortcuts sequentially.

Comment: Kote, looks like this works. I remember in VS 2013 that I wouldn't have to hit Ctrl+Alt+L before hitting Ctrl+U,R to run all the tests in a file. You suggestion works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kote answered by question. Basically locate the test file using Shift+Alt+L. You'll see it highlighted in Solution Explorer. then hit Ctrl+U,R and that will run all tests in the file.